# How do I auto-increment primary key from a custom number in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, auto-increment

I want to create a table say `my_movies` which has two columns `movie_id` and `name`.

I want to keep `movie_id` as primary key but the condition is that I want to start `movie_id` from 1000 and auto-increment by 2.

So I wrote this code:

```
insert into my_movies (movie_id, name)
values (1000, ABC), values(1002, XYZ)
```

How can I insert just names instead of inserting the movie_id? Eg.

```
insert into my_movies(PQR);
```

I know that if I declare as

```
 movie_id int not null identity(1,1) primary key
```

it starts to auto increment by 1 with first primary key as 1 without having to give the value of primary key when using insert command.

Thanks for any help.

Cheers,
Siddhesh

Comment: Seriously, you know " if I declare as "movie_id int not null identity(1,1) primary key "it starts to auto increment by 1 with first primary key as 1 ", and you can't figure out how to change the first key?

Comment: How about you guys stop bullying and help a school kid who's newbie to sql learn it . After all it is said "In vain have you acquired knowledge
if you have not imparted it to others." but thanks for your valuable answers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In identity the first parameter is the starting number and the second parameter will increment to the next digit. In this case the starting number will be 1000 and it will increase with 2 increment.

***movie_id int not null identity(1000,2) primary key***